# What is the average chain length of a glutaraldehyde crosslink between primary amines?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, amines

Imagine I'm performing a primary amine to primary amine (i.e. PA to PA) crosslinking reaction at $37~^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$ in phosphate-buffered saline (pH $\approx 7.4$) with glutaraldehyde drawn from a $4 \%$ stock solution stored at $\approx 4~{^\circ}\mathrm{C}$.  I've heard that glutaraldehyde, like other aldehydes, can self-polymerize via [aldol condensation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldol_condensation) under certain conditions.  What might be a good approximation for the number of PA-PA crosslinks that consist of a length $N=1$ chain of glutaraldehyde?